# Add New Column with Result from SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a `CubeBins` table showing bins with number of cubes and numbers of blue cubes, for example:

| Bin | TotalCubes | BlueCubes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 100 | 10 |
| 001 | 80 | 5 |

I have a select statement I'm using to calculate percentage of blue cubes:

```
SELECT BlueCubes, TotalCubes, 
       ROUND(BlueCubes * 100.0 / TotalCubes, 1) AS Percent
FROM CubeBins
```

Which returns the percentage without issue. However, I'm trying to insert a new `Percentage` column into the `CubeBins` table which will display the calculated percentage for each bin. I can't figure out how to add the Percent column to the table, can anyone offer some help?

Comment: If you're trying to add this new column back to the original table, you'd need to alter the table itself, unless you're managing this in memory with temp tables, CTEs, etc

Comment: Yes, I am trying to add it back to the original table.

Comment: If it is a computed column, why add the column to the table, you can do the calculation each time?  (which could be important if the values for the 2 fields you are using in calculation can change.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to add a column that is able to be calculated from other columns and simply returned. There is really no reason to add it unless there is something I am missing. If you are using SQL Server Management Studio you can create a calculated column and specify that formula as the column values. Generally it is bad design to have items stored that can be calculated from other items tho.

Comment: Thanks for these, I'm new enough to SQL that I guess I didn't understand that it's best to run the calculation each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite now supports generated columns so you can just do:

```
alter table cubebines add percent real
    (ROUND(BlueCubes * 100.0 / TotalCubes, 1)) virtual;
```